# How do I know when to start a word with "r-" or "wr-"?

Tags: orthography

How do I know when to spell a word with "r-" or "wr-"?

For example, [(wr)ap](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wrap) and [(r)ap](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rap), [(wr)ing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wring) and [(r)ing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ring). 
Both sets have the same *R* sound but different spellings.

Is there a way of working out which to use, or do I simply have to learn each word?

Comment: How do you know when to use *too to or two*?

Comment: _write_ and _right_ sound the same but are spelled differently and have different meanings.  You have to learn them individually.

Comment: Every word with "**wr**" has a slight but hearable "**w**" sound in them. Listen to how "*write*" is different from "*right*".

Comment: @SovereignSun You'd better write to Collins and AHD then, and tell them they need to make corrections.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's not what you think. Yes, pronunciation is the same but the feel is different. I can always figure out whether a person is saying "**write**" or "**right**".

Comment: @SovereignSun: what do you hear when one of the people is speaking who thinks that "copyright" is "copywrite"? There is no difference in pronunciation, whatever you think you hear.

Comment: @ColinFine Actually, in "**copyright**" the **r** is more intense while in "**copywrite**" the **r** is vague and smuged, the **w** sound is slightly hearable. Compare "**rat**" and "**wrong**".

Comment: @ColinFine At least that's the difference I hear everyday and was taught from audio lessons by native British teachers.

Comment: @ColinFine You can barely tell this difference and it is very gard to hear and impossible if a person doesn't make this difference when speaking.

Comment: There was a difference in the pronunciation of these words 500 years ago. There isn't today in any of the standard varieties of English.

Comment: @SoveriegnSun, I don't make this difference in speaking, and I don't know anybody else who does so. I don't know where it is you hear it. Perhaps with non-native speakers who have been taught to make a distinction that doesn't exist among native speakers?

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way other than to learn them.

[Words starting with "wr-" are almost always native English words, from Germanic roots, rather than borrowings from French or Latin; but that does not really give you much help].

Comment: I think there's some truth in the idea that "phonetic/phonemic clusters" may be associated with specific meanings. In which context my gut feeling is the percentage of words starting with ***wr-*** that have associations with "violence / effort" is probably much higher than the corresponding percentage for "ordinary" ***r-*** words. (I'm thinking of *wrack, wring, wreak, wreck, wrench, writhe, wrestle, wrangle,...*) Maybe we imported the entire "phonetic / semantic cluster" from Germanic roots (behind the scenes, so to speak).

Answer (score -1):

You have to get it right by reading written words instead of focussing on pronunciation. Once you will practice enough usage, you can understand what exactly the person is saying. Try to comprehend the context and you're good to go. Also, even though they sound almost same, there is 1% dissimilarity which you'll find, like commented by @SovereignSun.

Comment: Do you have evidence for your assertion that there is 1% dissimilarity?

Comment: There is a difference in lip motion which is experienced by many people, including me. So if you notice a person speaking you will find it.
You can find various forums where people have discussed the lip moment.

Comment: And this dissimilarity (which I do not believe in) is 1% of what? Speakers? Utterances? Words? And how do you know?